# Lion login screen

Tags: macos, screen, icon, user-account, login

I have a lot of users in my household (6 total + guest).  Is there a way to wrap or stack the user icons rather than having them scroll off the right part of the screen?

Comment: It's not an answer, but you know you can type the name to get to the off-screen items or just have people fill in the short name and password (if any). I hope someone has a better solution than an attempt to mitigate this layout.

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no way of changing the users list formatting.

The solution I use on our main computer is to simply disable the login icons and let users type their username/password.

To do so:

- go to "System Preferences"
- select "Users & Groups" [image]
- There chose login options [image]
- for the "Display Login Window as" option select "Name and Password" [image]